# Is it possible rename all files in a directory to 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc?

Tags: linux, windows, file, rename

I have a bunch of images (100+) in a directory, all with different names. Is there any way to rename them, possibly with a script (I'm running Windows), to 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc... without having to rename each one individually? I could launch a Linux virtual machine and copy them over if it isn't possible in Windows.

I've got this so far

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set MYDIR=F:\Pictures\Wallpapers
set /a count = 0
for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (
  echo %%x
  @echo !count!
  set /a count+=1
)
```

Which display the correct file name and the correct counter, but when I try

```
ren %%x !count!.jpg
```

Tells me "The system could not find the file specified."

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing the full path for the source file. Don't forget that `%%x` is just the file name; you need to prepend `%MYDIR%` to have a complete path:

```
ren %MYDIR%\%%x !count!.jpg
```

Comment: Doh! Thx! Worked for every file but a few, but those had spaces in the name, guessing that's what threw it off, but a whole easier to just rename four instead of 100+.